# Safe Alternative to gets

Tags: c++, c, fgets, gets

I wanna read a whole line from standard input, including the whitespace between two words.

When using gets on gcc I get the following message:

```
send.c:(.text+0x2a): warning: the `gets' function is dangerous and should not be used.
```

What's a better alternative?