# gets() does not read user input

Tags: c, gets

I am new to linked list, now I have little problems in population of nodes.

Here I could populate first node of linked list but the `gets()` function doesn't seems to pause the execution to fill the next node.

Output is like:

```
Var name : var
Do you want to continue ?y
Var name : Do you want to continue ?  // Here I cannot input second data
```

Here is my code:

```
struct data
{
    char name[50];
    struct data* next;
};
struct data* head=NULL;
struct data* current=NULL;
void CreateConfig()
{
    head = malloc(sizeof(struct data));
    head->next=NULL;
    current = head;
    char ch;
    while(1)
    {
        printf("Var name : ");
        gets(current->name);    //Here is the problem,
        printf("Do you want to continue ?");
        ch=getchar();
        if(ch=='n')
        {
            current->next=NULL;
            break;
        }
        current->next= malloc(sizeof(struct data));
        current=current->next;
    }
}
```

Comment: maybe you need to do type cast, add `(data *)` before every `malloc`, like this `(data *) malloc(sizeof(struct data))`

Comment: @runnerup: That is a bad idea: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1565496/specifically-whats-dangerous-about-casting-the-result-of-malloc

Comment: What is the problem you are seeing exactly? Does the program crash or something else?

Comment: function "malloc" returns a void pointer, you should manually convert it to (data*) type

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This happens because:

```
ch=getchar();
```

read either `y` or `n` from the input and assigns to `ch` but there a newline in the input buffer which gets read by the `gets` in the next iteration.

To fix that you need to consume the newline following the `y/n` the user enters. To do that you can add another call to `getchar()` as:

```
ch=getchar(); // read user input
getchar();    // consume newline
```

Also the function `fgets` should be used in place of `gets`. [Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4309746/safe-alternative-to-gets)

Answer (score 2):

It's exactly what @codaddict said. You need to clean the buffer.

```
void fflushstdin( void )
{
    int c;
    while( (c = fgetc( stdin )) != EOF && c != '\n' );
}
```

You can read this links that explains it very well:

1. [c-faq](http://c-faq.com/stdio/gets_flush2.html)
2. And this [mdsn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9yky46tz%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) if you are on windows.

One more thing, try to always use fgets -instead of gets-, as it is impossible to prevent buffer overflows if you are using gets.

You could read the section "Use of safe libraries" at this [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow)

Answer (score 0):

you should also add a line like

```
 current->next = 0;
```

after

```
 current=current->next;
```

to ensure that the last element's next is not dangling.