# Runtime exception with input using scanf or gets in C

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010, input

I am trying to get input from the console with this code but it gives me runtime exception at some memory location each time I try to run it and enter the first possible input.
I am using Visual Studio 2010. I got same problems with MingW and Dev C++. However, the code ran fine with the old TurboC3 compiler.

```
int Nowhere(int x);
...
char* AtBashEncrypt(char* message);
char* AtBashDecrypt(char* encrypted);

int main()
{
    char *input = "", *ciphertext = "", *plaintext = "";
    system("cls");
    printf("AtBash Cipher\nEnter a string to be encrypted: ");
    gets(input); //this is where I get the error
    ciphertext = AtBashEncrypt(input);
    ...
    getch();
}
```

What could possibly be wrong with it?

Comment: you haven't allocated memory for input var.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 char *input = "";
```

is a pointer pointing to a string literal residing in read only memory you cannot modify its contents. Any attempt to do so results in undefined behavior. What you need is an array.

```
#define MAX_SIZE 256
char input[MAX_SIZE]="";
```

**Good Read:**
[What is the difference between char a[] = ?string?; and char *p = ?string?;?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9460260/what-is-the-difference-between-char-a-string-and-char-p-string)

Also, you should **[use fgets instead of gets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4309746/safe-alternative-to-gets)**

Comment: And not only that, `gets()` is a broken function that should never ever be used (because it's almost impossible to avoid buffer overflows).

Comment: @JacobAbrahams: The argument is not valid because *even if was writable* is a assumption that does not hold good in this case.

Comment: @JohnZwinck: True, indeed.

Comment: @NikhilGirraj: Because Undefined behavior does not necessarily mandate a segmentation fault, Undefined behavior means that the observed behavior simply cannot be defined, it can be anything from a crash to normal working of program to blowing up your computer(*theoretically*). On a side note, turbo compiler is quite old and bug prone and you should consider moving to a more stable and updated compiler like gcc or msvc or clang.

Comment: @AlokSave: That helps! I think I should start reading more about it, any suggestions will be again very helpful.