# In C, how to stop gets() printing a newline form previous input?

Tags: c, newline, stdio, gets

I'm having problems while using gets in C.

```
...
int main()
{
    char test[20], m[20];
    int n;

    scanf("%d", &n);

    while(n)
    {   
        gets(test);
        test.kolona = n;

        m = decode(test); //some function

        printf("%s",m.sif);
        putchar('\n');

        scanf("%d", &n);
    }
}
```

When I enter a number and press enter, it automatically "prints" a newline, before you input the string. I searched a bit and found that this can be avoided if you put a gets before, like this:

```
...
scanf("%d", &n);
gets(test)

while(n);
{
    gets(test);
    ...
}
```

But then it messes up again as the loop continues :(

Is there an elegant solution to this?

Comment: Never use `gets`. It's so bad it was even removed from the C standard in 1999. Look at `fgets`. (Which still includes the line-ending `\n`.) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-dangerous-why-should-it-not-be-used https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4309746/safe-alternative-to-gets

Comment: And the way to go is, get the line with `fgets` and then scan it for whatever you want with `sscanf` or whatever.

Comment: I'm affraid that new line inserting is not causęd by gets() fgets() scanf() or any of these functions. This is console aplication behaviour.

Comment: @Deduplicator I would normally use scanf... but I'm doing a problem at SPOJ and I'm constantly getting wrong answer error... I found a [suggestion](https://www.spoj.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=41&t=10855&sid=e9b4a3ceb5f93725c65a8d5b22379661) on their forum to use gets, to deal with any kind of input(test cases)...

Comment: Just read the two questions I linked for why that's terrible advice.

Answer (score 0):

sample to fix

```
int main()
{
    char test[20], m[20];
    int n;

    scanf("%d%*c", &n);//skip the newline following the numeric input

    while(n)
    {   
        scanf("%19[\^n]", test);//gets has been abolished.
        //test.kolona = n;//The array does not have a member field.

        //strcpy(m, decode(test));//m = decode(test); //Can not be assigned to the array in this way 

        printf("%s\n", m);
        //putchar('\n');

        scanf("%d%*c", &n);
    }
}
```

Comment: I will check what your modifications do, thanks. As for the things you commented out, I made a struct in the original, and didn't fix everything so it would look good in the example.